# Should i cache data in my server or Just rely on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a website which runs on Heroku and i am using Mongo Atlas as my database. I have tested the mongo connection speeds and found its around 5ms to 20ms based on the data what i am retrieving
Note: Both Heroku app and Mongo Atlas are in same aws zone.

Now my question is i have a collection with around 10K records which my users query frequently. For this usecase should i cache those 10K records in the server or should i leave it to MongoDB and live with the ~15ms overhead? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just one MongoDB call then i would say do not cache and leave it to the MongoDB to cache. In a real world scenario average response time will be around 300ms to 900ms (based on my pingdom results for my website) so when you compare the delay with the response time its relatively very low. So you are saving like a 15ms from ~900ms. 
So better stay with the mongoDB for cleaner code and easy maintenance.

Comment: Make sense. I'll never checked my response times. I'll check that too. For now i'll go with MongoDB caching.